# Verify expectations on a mock?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

In the [documentation for Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/Wiki/Default.aspx?Page=Rhino%20Mocks%203.5&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#CreateMockisdeprecated,replacedbyStrictMockTheuseofStrictMockisdiscouraged) it states that you must verify expectations on a mock which must be verified/asserted later using either the VerifyAllExpectations() or AssertWasCalled() methods.

However if I comment out the verification the test still passes. So I am wondering why you would need to have the verify expectation call at all.

```
...
notificationSvc.Expect(o => o.UserIsLoggedOut());       
...
//notificationSvc.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

Comment: Pls post some more code about how you're setting up your notificationSvc Mock.

Comment: I am using sample code from documentation (link above) under section "Expect() Extension Method"

Comment: The code that you have posted is from the Stub extension method. Stubs and Mocks are two different animals ! http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

Comment: I apologise, I meant section "Stub() Extension Method" . However the section you mention also uses a mock with Expect and VerifyAllExpectations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifying an Expectation is as vital to a test case, as is an Assert statement is for a Test.

You can write any amount of code without Assert statements in a Test method, It would pass. 
But the question is - "Is it *Testing* anything ?"

The Assert statement(s) are the **crux** of the Test Case.

Similarly the Verify methods are the crux of all Expectation calls, without Verify method your test case is as good as a Test case without an Assert statement.

A System interaction could be verified using Expectations, It's a three step proccess

1. **Setting Expectations**: Letting know the mocking framework what interactions are you expecting to be invoked.
2. **Interact or Perform actions:**: Perform the actual call which you want to test on the SUT(System Under Test)
3. **Verifying Expections:** Asking the mocking framework to Verify all the expectations were met while performing Step 2.

Comment: It seems like a really easy mistake to make, to set expectations and forget to verify them, especially if using multiple mocked objects. That Rhino doesn't appear to warn you of this is rather dangerous, IMO, as you can believe your tests are passing!

Answer (score 1):

When you are performing the unit testing, you are not just testing the expectations of the component that you are testing, you are also testing the expectations of the component you are testing and *how it interacts with other components it relies on*.

Let's say that you mock a repository & unit of work pattern interfaces and pass mocks of them to your component.  While the component might give you the right result if you tell the repository to return certain data, you want to verify that the implementations of the interfaces were called in the way that you expect them to.  This is what verification is for.

When combined with testing the results of the processing your component does, you have a much more definitive test of not only what it will do, but how it will interact with the components that it requires to do it.

Comment: Am i not testing the interaction and implementation with the other component with the line notificationSvc.Expect(o => o.UserIsLoggedOut());?

Comment: @Noel: If notificationSvc is the mock, and the call to UserIsLogged out is the only call that you expect, then yes, I'd say that's what you are testing.  I'm not familiar with what VerifyAll will do, or if it places any additional expectations, so you should check the documentation to make sure you aren't missing something.

Answer (score 0):

When removing the Verify, the test isn't really testing much at all (other then possible exceptions that might get generated).

Essentially, you aren't testing the interaction of your tested object with your mock at all.